# break more than 1 level of foreach nesting in tcl

Tags: foreach, tcl, break

Is it possible to exit in 1 command, from two levels of nesting? That is, let us say I have this code:

```
foreach l { 1 2 3 4 } {
   foreach k { 3 4 5 6 } {
      if { $k > 4 } {
         break2
      } else {
         puts "$k $l"
   }
}
```

What that I would like to see output is:

> 1 3
>   1 4

The question is, how can one code the break2 (if possible)?.
I do not know of such "feature" in any language, other than wrapping this in a proc, and using return to stop the proc, which is more of a hack than proper language construct
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do it directly; the `break` machinery doesn't have anything to trace up to anything other than the nearest looping context.

The easiest way of handling this is to use `try` in 8.6 and a custom exception code (i.e., any value from 5 upwards).

```
foreach a {b c} {
    puts "a=$a; to show that this is not stopping the outermost loop"
    try {
        foreach l { 1 2 3 4 } {
            foreach k { 3 4 5 6 } {
                if { $k > 4 } {
                    # Generating a custom exception code is a bit messy
                    return -level 0 -code 5
                }
                puts "$k $l"
            }
        }
    } on 5 {} {
        # Do nothing here; we've broken out
    }
}
```

Running that gives this output:

```
a=b; to show that this is not stopping the outermost loop
3 1
4 1
a=c; to show that this is not stopping the outermost loop
3 1
4 1
```

But it's pretty messy to do this; the best approach is typically to refactor your code so that you can just `return` ordinarily to end the loop. Using `apply` might make this easier:

```
foreach a {b c} {
    puts "a=$a; to show that this is not stopping the outermost loop"
    apply {{} {
        foreach l { 1 2 3 4 } {
            foreach k { 3 4 5 6 } {
                if { $k > 4 } {
                    return
                }
                puts "$k $l"
            }
        }
    }}
}
```

The downside of using `apply` is that it is a different variable context and has quite a bit more overhead (because of all the stack frame management). Still, the variable context thing can be worked around using `upvar` if you're careful.

Comment: The `apply` trick won't work in 8.4 or before. Those versions are not currently supported.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in Tcl ≥ 8.5:

```
foreach l { 1 2 3 4 } {
    foreach k { 3 4 5 6 } {
        if {$k > 4} {
            return -code break -level 2
        } else {
            puts "$k $l"
        }
    }
}
```

That `return -code break -level 2` works like "make the enclosing command two levels up the stack return as if it has called `break`".

The [`return` command manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm).

Comment: From this follows, of course, that the `break2` command can be implemented as `proc break2 {} {return -code break -level 3}`.

Comment: @PeterLewerin, I'd then vote for `proc Break level { incr level; return -code break -level $level }` ;-)

Comment: my god it's full of levels

Comment: It's levels all the way down.

Comment: That doesn't work. The levels refer to procedure calls only.

Comment: Hi.<br>It did not work for me. See output
    
     3 1
     4 1
     command returned bad code: 2
        while executing
        "foreach l { 1 2 3 4 } {
              foreach k { 3 4 5 6 } {
                 if {$k > 4} {
                      return -code break -level 2
                 } else {
                   puts "$..."

Comment: Yes. *blushes* Since the `foreach` commands evaluate their scripts in an `uplevel`, all loops actually live in the same level as where the first `foreach` is called. The only reason the code in this answer seemed to work was that a `return -code break -level 2` actually breaks the loops with a `return` code (there aren't enough levels to get the `break` code), which isn't reported by, say, `tkcon` (`tclsh` gives the "bad code: 2" (= return) message.)